# initializeCulture of pages fires before the selectedIndexChange of dropdownlist in masterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, internationalization, event-handling

I have a masterpage with a language selector dropdownlist

it has multiple subpages using the masterpage but, in the subpages (i created a basePage class which i then let the pages inherit from) i override the initializeCulture.
like this:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            String selectedLanguage = Common.SessionManager.Language;

            if (selectedLanguage == "")
            {
                selectedLanguage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("defaultLanguage");
            }

            if (selectedLanguage == "")
            {
                selectedLanguage = "nl-BE";
            }

            UICulture = selectedLanguage;
            Culture = selectedLanguage;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);

            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
```

on the SelectedIndexChanged event of the dropdownlist, i set the new language in the session
like this:

```
    protected void LanguageSelectorSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sCulture = LanguageSelector.SelectedValue;
        Common.SessionManager.Language = sCulture;
    }
```

but the initializeCulture has then already been fired.

so i have sort of a delay effect, page loads with previous language, and on the next postback its translated correctly.

i cannot call the initializeCulture again, because i'm on a masterpage and i have no access to the subpage's basePage class.

anyone got an idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in this case is to redirect the page to itself after changing the language.

Comment: If anything fails i will have to try and force a refresh this way yes, but i'm looking into clean ways first :)

Comment: Where do you see something unclean? It’s a one liner in your event handler and the state of your page is repaired in a natural way – with the next request. The changing of the language is a rare event therefore the additional effort isn’t important.

Comment: i did not really mean its dirty, but it would rock to do partial updates instead of a whole refresh of the page... as the client already mentioned they don't want to many flickering for reloads...
thats why i said i want to try all options and if they don't work or proof to be too mutch work for implementation, i will use a refresh eventually. but i want to see what is possible first.

Comment: adding a second refresh to a page in this way is not a proper solution to this creating unnecessary work for the server

Comment: @Chris McGrath: And what is your recommendation? It is possible to use Server.Transfer – one of the other answers. But this does not reflect the change in culture in the url => problems with back navigation. Additional work for the server? One redirect for each change of the culture. Negligible.

Comment: Adding additional postbacks to workaround a language switching issue  is not really a solution to the actual problem and is creating double the work for the server. In a small app this might be non issue to you, but when you have a national or global website that generates thousands of concurrent users this will in the end affect scalability and increase costs there is a proper solution to this problem. I am here for the same reason, to find a solution, the proper solution... not a workaround or a hack

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the selected language by form posted values:

```
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        String selectedLanguage = Common.SessionManager.Language;

        if (Request.Form.ContainsKey(myLanguageDropDown.ClientID)
            selectedLanguage = Request.Form[myLanguageDropDown.ClientID];

        if (selectedLanguage == "")
        {
        ...
```

Comment: the thing is,  i cannot get  myLanguageDropDown in that context, as the drop down is on the masterpage, while this initializeCulture is located in the pages itself (trough means of a basePage that inherits from System.web.ui.Page...  So i cannot request that dropdown.ClientID

Comment: You can, if you set the <%@ MasterType %> directive

Comment: Thanks for that idea, but it still does not seem to work, i can access the drop down list from the sattelite page now, but it does not ever have a value selected...  selectedIndex is always -1

Comment: but, have you tried getting the selected index using Request.Form ?

Comment: oh darn i totally misread your post on that, i did not, i tried getting the Master.Master.DropDownListId.SelectedIndex....  let me try that Request form right away

Comment: Ok, so i tried the request.form but its completely empty, by the way, getting the dropdownlists client id seems to be bugged also, i get the regular id instead of the client ID when requesting it from outside the master page, but that doesnt matter since the request.form is empty in that context.  Still, thanks for the help it just seems like hard refreshing the page on language change will have to be done... :s

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the event handler for the dropdownlist because that happens after `InitializeCulture()`.
`InitializeCulture()` happens before the request values are loaded into the form controls.

So the correct way to obtain the value from the dropdownlist is to NOT use the event handler, and use `Request.Form["yourddlid"]` inside `InitializeCulture()` to get the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

In the same vein of the "Redirect to itself" answer you could use Server.Transfer() instead of Redirect, avoiding a round-trip to the client. Something like this (consider it's in the Default.aspx page):

```
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (Session["LCID"] != null)
        {
            int lcid = (int)Session["LCID"];
            CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo(lcid);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = c;
        }
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }

    protected void comboCultures_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID);
        if (comboCultures.SelectedItem != null)
            c = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Convert.ToInt32(comboCultures.SelectedItem.Value));
        Session["LCID"] = c.LCID;
        Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
    }
```

I've stored the LCID of the culture in the combo box values, but this is not important. The heart of the technique is to user Server.Transer(pagename) so that the page workflow is reinitiated and the Page.InitializeCulture has a chance to get the "current" values from the Session.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void InitializeCulture(){
   Page.UICulture = Request.Form["ddlLanguage"];
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.