# Page switches language in Master Page but not in PageContent until refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, multilingual, page-lifecycle

I am currently working on a site that requires switching between French and English we are using .resx string files and CurrentCulture + CurrentUICulture

We currently have a Button that switches the culture as part of our master page that calls a block of code to do the switch and sets a cookie to remember the language between visits

The problem we are having is that the MasterPage switches languages  as expected but the page content retains the old language until the next page load

**BaseMaster Class** (All Master Pages Inherit from this )

```
    public class BaseMaster : MasterPage
    {
        protected void btn_Language_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tools.ToggleLanguage();
        }
    }
```

**BasePage Class** (All pages in site inherit from this)

```
    public class BasePage : Page {



    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        base.InitializeCulture();
        Tools.CheckLanguageCookie();

    }

}
```

**Language Switching**

```
    public static void ToggleLanguage()
    {
        var lang = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "en" ? "fr-CA" : "en-CA";

        SetLanguage(lang);
    }

    public static void SetLanguage(string language)
    {
        if (language != "en-CA" && language != "fr-CA")
            language = "en-CA";

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Lang"){Value = language, Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)};
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);

    }

    public static void CheckLanguageCookie()
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Lang"];

        SetLanguage(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : "en-CA");
    }
```

Comment: Possible help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028371/initializeculture-of-pages-fires-before-the-selectedindexchange-of-dropdownlist