# Get Selected Value from DropDownList inside UserControl for Globalization

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu, localization, globalization

I need to get the selected value of a dropdown list to change the language of an app, but I get an object reference not set to an instance error reading from Request.Form.

The dropdown list in the Page.ascx sets the language. Which thing goes through UserPage class which inherits a BasePage class.

I have a dropdown list to select the user-defined language for the app.

**Page.ascx**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
           <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">English</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="fr-CA">French</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="es-MX">Spanish</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The problem is here:

```
 string selectedValue = Request.Form[Request[PostBackEventTarget]].ToString();
```

**BasePage.cs**
      public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

```
    public const string PostBackEventTarget = "__EVENTTARGET";

    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {

        if (Request[PostBackEventTarget] != null)
        {
            string controlID = Request[PostBackEventTarget];

            //split to get friendly ID
            string[] ddlcontrol = controlID.Split('$');


            if (ddlcontrol[1] == "ddlLanguage")
            {
                // the control will appear as _ctl4%24ddlLanguage or _ctl9%24ddlLanguage, etc.

                //Request.Form has the right name inside __EVENTTARGET
                // but the ToString bombs
                string selectedValue = Request.Form[Request[PostBackEventTarget]].ToString();

                SetCulture(selectedValue, selectedValue);

            }
        }
        if (Session["MyUICulture"] != null && Session["MyCulture"] != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = (CultureInfo)Session["MyUICulture"];
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo)Session["MyCulture"];
        }
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }

    protected void SetCulture(string name, string locale)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(name);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(locale);
        Session["MyUICulture"] = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        Session["MyCulture"] = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    }
```

//etc...

I used these articles to start initially:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15313/Globalization-and-localization-demystified-in-ASP
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

The app is from Version 1.0 that has been updated to 4.0, but I still cannot use Master templates.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: why you don't use SelectedIndexChanged event or selecteditem, selectedvalue methods?

Comment: The controls are not available at this point. Vivek Thakur (author of second link) says, "This method is called much earlier in the Page lifecycle and we don't have access to any controls in this stage, so have to use Form collection."

Comment: I did a variation of this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9896963/970008